# Close semantic multi dropdown on select

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, html-select, semantic-ui

I want to close [semantic multiple](https://semantic-ui.com/modules/dropdown.html#multiple-selection) dropdown whenever option is select from dropdown i have tried but cant do that.
here is my code.

```
$('.ui.multiple.dropdown').dropdown({
  onAdd: function (value, text, $selected) {
     $('.dropdown')
       .dropdown({
           action: 'hide'
       })
     }
 });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the field is blurred (like when user clicks anywhere else in the page), the active dropdown closes by itself.

So triggering a blur event `onAdd` should do the trick.

```
$('.ui.multiple.dropdown').dropdown({
  onAdd: function (value, text, $selected) {
    $('.dropdown').blur();
  }
});
```

Comment: You can use `$('.dropdown').dropdown('hide');` too.
Not sure which is best, but I assume the "blur" listener would chain that action itself, so you might want to call it yourself in the first place